# AppleScript: Call handler inside tell statement

Tags: applescript, handler, tell

I get this error everytime i run this script: System Events got an error: "Test123" doesn’t understand the notify message.

Code:

```
--more code...
tell application "System Events"
    if some_system_events_property then
         my notify of "Test123" thru "Test"
    end if
end tell
--more code...
to notify of message thru level
    display dialog message with titel level
end notify
```

I have tried to replace

```
my notify of "Test123" thru "Test"
```

with the following, without any success:

```
notify of "Test123" thru "Test" of me
(notify of "Test123" thru "Test") of me
```

Comment: what is this 'of "Test123" thru "Test"'  ?? that makes no sense to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if some_system_events_property then
        tell me to notify of "Test123" thru "Test"
    end if
end tell

to notify of message thru level
    display dialog message with title level
end notify
```

Although I'll also say that I never use the direct parameter syntax for AppleScript handlers, preferring positional parameters (i.e., `notify( message, level )`), as it avoids the ambiguous syntax troubles you discovered.

Answer (score 6):

not exactly sure what your trying to do but here is an example of how to call a function and pass parameter

```
tell application "System Events"
    set m to "message content"
    my notify(m)
end tell
--more code...
on notify(message)
    display dialog (message)
end notify
```